A determinant leading to differential equations
This exercise comes from a book used for preparation in French Classes Préparatoires. The original problem can be found here: https://i.sstatic.net/H3vr0MrO.jpg
Below is my translation of the problem:
Find all $\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions such that:
$$
\left|
\begin{matrix}
y & y' & y'' \\
y' & y'' & y \\
y'' & y & y'
\end{matrix}
\right| = 0
$$
I applied properties of determinants and simplified the expression to obtain the following result:
$$
-\frac{1}{2}(y + y' + y'')\left((y - y')^2 + (y' - y'')^2 + (y'' - y)^2\right) = 0.
$$
From this, I concluded that either
$$y + y' + y'' = 0$$
or
$$
(y - y')^2 + (y' - y'')^2 + (y'' - y)^2 = 0 \implies y = y' = y''.
$$
My question is: can I assume that I should solve both cases independently, i.e., $y + y' + y'' = 0$ or $y = y' = y''$? Should I also check the scenario where both conditions are true at the same time to see if it leads to a contradiction?
These questions relate to a specific part of the solution (highlighted in the attached image). Thank you for your insights!

Yes you solve both independently. You have shown that an OR statement must be true, so either one, or the other, or both statements need to be true

@whpowell96 Can you understand the highlighted part in the attached solution from the book? I have posted the same question in a French forum. Here is the answer I received.

@whpowell96 La difficulté c’est que la condition a été réécrite sous la forme fg=0 sur R où f et g sont deux fonctions et la correction semble suggérer que soit f est nulle (sur R) soit g est nulle. En réalité, on ne peut dans un premier temps dire que si x est un nombre réel, alors soit y''(x)+y'(x)+y(x)=0, soit y''(x)=y'(x)=y(x)=0. Il manque une légère explication qui permet d’expliquer la suite du raisonnement et la conclusion. La partie encadrée y répond en partie.

@whpowell96  The difficulty lies in the fact that the condition has been rewritten in the form ( fg = 0 ) on ( \mathbb{R} ), where ( f ) and ( g ) are two functions, and the correction seems to suggest that either ( f ) is zero (on ( \mathbb{R} )) or ( g ) is zero. In reality, we can only initially state that if ( x ) is a real number, then either ( y''(x) + y'(x) + y(x) = 0 ) or ( y''(x) = y'(x) = y(x) = 0 ). There is a slight missing explanation that would clarify the continuation of the reasoning and the conclusion. The highlighted section partially addresses this.

I suppose you are right that there could be a solution that satifies condition (1) on some interval and smoothly switches to condition (2) in a $C^2$ way. That sounds tedious to check

@whpowell96 Yes but this comes from the oral part of the examination from the Ecole Polytechnique. So, I guess, the solution would sophisticated but not tedious. Thank you very much for spending the time with my question.

It's not so bad to check: For such a solution, by continuity there is some $a \in \Bbb R$ where both $y(a) = y'(a) = y''(a)$ and $y(a) + y'(a) + y''(a) = 0$. At every such $a$, we have $y(a) = y'(a) = y''(a) = 0$, so...
